# iOS memory allocation issue & RIPZoneDataAlloc

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I have an RSS reader-type app that I'm running through instruments and I'm seeing alot of allocations from RIPZoneDataAlloc:

[image]

What does RIPZoneDataAlloc do exactly?

Also after maybe a dozen page transitions including alot of UIWebViews, I'm seeing almost 10mb live bytes. If I run leaks I see trivial leaks. Does 10mb sound like an issue? Does it indicate that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It's best to ship a leak free version.

Comment: what if I see trivial leaks in instruments but I see alot of live bytes adding up - does this indicate programmer error or is the app just memory hungry?

Comment: 10 mb isn't a lot for an app, and define "trivial".  Are we talking bytes, Kb, Mb?  Also, you wouldn't happen to be using `-colorWithPatternImage:`, would you?

Comment: not using colorWithPatternImage, but I am using alot of uiwebviews which are known to be memory hogs. trivial - tens of bytes

Comment: Wow, that is trivial... where is it coming from?  (UIWebView?)

Comment: libsystem_c.dylib whatever that is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13288/discussion-between-codafi-and-user1492272)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIPZoneDataAlloc is apparently responsible for a high amount of memory allocations, especially those that deal with UIColor's colorWithPatternImage: method, which is known to be a memory hog.

10mb is a perfectly reasonable amount of memory consumption for an application.  I have a fairly complicated app that consumes about 30mb on average, so that's perfectly reasonable. I'd be more concerned if your app was spiking memory usage at about 50-70 mb.

As for those leaks, they are trivial enough that you can ignore them.  Mostly because you have no power to fix system-level frameworks.